# Approval Process - Error need to change/delete

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process

I don't want to show the error message page/url when the record doesn't meet the criteria.

[image]

I want to de-activate the "Submit for Approval button", if record doesn't meet the criteria.

Comment: This requires jQuery (to hide the button) on a VF page with an `apex:detail` tag - and you'll need a Boolean formula field on the page that indicates whether the record meets the entry criteria

Comment: @crop1645 Disagree. If your entry criteria are simple enough, you can recreate them in a formula and use a formula button that only displays when the record can be submitted.

Comment: This [question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12595/buttons-with-dynamic-titles-in-formula-field-buttons) might help.

Comment: @AdrianLarson hmm - I was thinking of how to disable the OOB `Submit for Approval` button but your solution is clever

Comment: Gotta think *outside* the box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the standard button, you are going to need to pursue some hack-y, unsupported workarounds. However if you are open to using a formula "button" you have more options. It would look something like:

```
IF( 
    Can_Submit__c,
    HYPERLINK( 
        "/p/process/Submit?id=" & Id & "&retURL=" & Id & "&saveURL=" & Id, 
        IMAGE(
            "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01580000001Iub9", 
            "Click Here to Submit For Approval", 
            30,100), 
        "_self" 
    ),
    "This record cannot be submitted for approval."
)
```

The `Id` in that `file` parameter is for a `Document` that contains the button image you want to display.

Comment: Refer this       :  http://ofthecloud.blogspot.in/2013/09/custom-alert-message-on-salesforce.html

Comment: for hiding the Submit for approval button from the Approval history (Related List) i need to write the Jscript/Jquery for the same. Or any another solution for this ?